# Send a Push Notification from a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, contactbuilder, push-notification

My problem is - I want to send a push notification using a journey, but I can't get the ContactKey of a MobilePush contact and admit it into a data extension (it doesn't exist in the _PushAddress data view).

So my question is: is there any way to **get the Contact Key of a MobilePush contact** in order to use it in a data extension as an entry source to a journey. If not, is there any way to send a push notification to a contact based on his ContactID (ContactID does exist in _PushAddress).

Thanks in advance to all the contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that a entry source DE for JB contain SubscriberKey. The requirement is that the DE must be a sendable DE. You can make a sendable relationship by mapping a field to SubscriberId (contactid)

You will not be able to get a new dataview created called '[All Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_all_contacts.htm&type=5)'

You can also make a 'Filtered List' in Mobile Push and use this as an '[Audience Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_audience.htm&type=5)'

Answer (score 3):

The subscriberKey field is in the _Subscribers data view as well as the _SubscriberID.

You can use a SQL query with the _Subscribers data view and _PushAdress then join them using SubscriberID and ContactID respetively:

```
SELECT s.SubscriberKey
FROM _Subscribers s
INNER JOIN _PushAddress p  WITH (nolock)
 ON s.SubscriberID = p.[_ContactID]
WHERE <your filter conditions>
```

Comment: That's actually a great solution. The problem is that what if I want to get the contact key of an anonymous contact (a one that has been created in mobile push and not in the subscribers - since the subscribers data view is only relevant for email subscribers).

Comment: To do so you have to open a case and ask them to create a new dataView with the data of AllContacts, that may have costs associated.

Comment: There is a contact record in Subscribers data that relates to the device.  If no subscriber key is present in the device registration, a random GUID is assigned instead.  So the join to the subscribers table will pull back a subscriber based on the ContactID field for each device, even if it's anonymous.